# Will changing recycle times cause app pool to reset?

Tags: iis, application-pools

We have an app pool that is currently set to recycle at 1:30am and 5:30am. I would like to remove the 5:30am entry so that it only recycles once a day.

Will this update cause the application pool to reset when I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your update will not cause the application pool to reset.  Modifying the specific times that an application pool recycles will not cause the application pool to immediately recycle.  You can verify this for yourself if you like by running perfmon and capturing the "Total Application Pool Recycles" counter of the "APP_POOL_WAS" object while you modify the recycle settings.  That counter will increment every time an application pool is recycled.